# How use two v-navigation-drawer?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to use two v-navigation-drawer in my application.
I want to put the second v-navigation-drawer on v-content of the v-app.

This image, I put the sample image inside v-content.

Because, I created the routes. And when clicked in item of the second v-navigation-drawer, will open the other component next to v-navigation-drawer.

Ex:

1. blabla/settings/profile
2. blabla/settings/conf

Link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So the routes are kind of nested according to your examples: a `Settings` in 1st Drawer and `Profile & Conf` in 2nd/child drawer. Let's call those `Nested Routes`.

1) If you wish to have those drawers as you wished, you need to create:

1 `MainDrawer.vue` component that wraps 1 `ChildDrawer.vue` child component which contains/wraps the `<router-view>` (if you're using `vue-router`). You will have to connect the links by append `<router-link to="/settings/profile">` and other routes under Settings. You will have to toggle the drawer "open" state of 2nd child drawer if reached /profile or /config routes.

2) Instead of that approach, Vuetify has `Nested List`(link [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#nested-lists)) that solves your child routes with `v-list-group` component up to 2 levels in-depth (which is sufficient for your case as well).